# How to observe objects count on realm db

Tags: ios, swift, realm, reactive-swift

I want to observe the object count of the realm DB.
I wrote this approach:

```
let realm = try? Realm()
self.notificationToken = realm?.objects(AnalyticsEventDto.self).observe { _ in
    if let count = realm?.objects(AnalyticsEventDto.self).count {
        observer.send(value: count)
    }
}
```

There is another way to do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `RealmCollectionChange` parameter rather than creating a new `Results` object in the closure. This also lets you handle the error:

```
let realm = try? Realm()
self.notificationToken = realm?.objects(AnalyticsEventDto.self).observe { change in
    switch change {
    case .initial(let results):
        observer.send(value: results.count)
    case .update(let results, deletions: _, insertions: _, modifications: _):
        observer.send(value: results.count)
    case .error(let error):
        observer.send(error: error)
    }
}
```

But a more ReactiveSwifty way of doing this might be to wrap the entire Realm collection notification API to make it reactive. This is a bit involved, but it is more general and potentially usable in multiple places in your code:

```
/// We want to send errors via the `ReactiveSwift` error event, so create a new `CollectionChange` enum that
/// mimics `RealmCollectionChange` except it doesn't have an `error` case.
enum CollectionChange<CollectionType> {
    case initial(CollectionType)
    case update(CollectionType, deletions: [Int], insertions: [Int], modifications: [Int])
}

/// Extending `ReactiveExtensionsProvider` and `Reactive` is the standard way to add reactive extensions
/// to existing types in a way that avoids name collisions.
extension Results: ReactiveExtensionsProvider { }

extension Reactive where Base: RealmCollection {
    /// This wraps Realm collection notifications in a very general reactive way.
    private func changeNotificationsRaw() -> SignalProducer<RealmCollectionChange<Base>, Never> {
        return SignalProducer { [base = self.base] observer, lifetime in
            let token = base.observe { change in
                observer.send(value: change)
            }

            lifetime.observeEnded {
                token.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    /// This just maps `RealmCollectionChange` to our own `CollectionChange` type while translating errors
    /// to ReactiveSwift error events.
    func changeNotifications() -> SignalProducer<CollectionChange<Base>, Error> {
        return changeNotificationsRaw().flatMap(.concat) { realmChange -> SignalProducer<CollectionChange<Base>, Error> in
            switch realmChange {
            case .initial(let collection):
                return SignalProducer(value: .initial(collection))
            case let .update(collection, deletions, insertions, modifications):
                return SignalProducer(value: .update(collection, deletions: deletions, insertions: insertions, modifications: modifications))
            case .error(let err):
                return SignalProducer(error: err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
realm.objects(AnalyticsEventDto.self).reactive.changeNotifications()
    .map { change -> Int in
        switch change {
        case .initial(let results):
            return results.count
        case .update(let results, _, _, _):
            return results.count
        }
    }
    .take(during: self.lifetime)
    .start { event in
        print(event)
    }
```